# Norm type in cost function of ANN

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, mathematics, cost-function

I'm reading [a tutorial about ANN](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/neural-networks-tutorial/). They use the following cost function:

[image]

As you can see this equation includes a norm. I'm new to the concept of norm.

My question is what kind of norm they use here (There are Absolute-value norm, Euclidean norm, Euclidean norm of a complex number, Taxicab norm, Manhattan norm, p-norm, Maximum norm, infinity norm, uniform norm, supremum norm, Zero norm, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the article they state that

> The two vertical lines represent the $L^2$ norm of the error, or what is known as the sum-of-squares error (SSE)

Otherwise known as the Euclidean norm, Euclidean length, $L^2$ distance, $ℓ^2$ distance, $L^2$ norm, $ℓ^2$ norm, $2$-norm, or square norm.

Also speaking from my experience, most of the time when a norm is specified without a subscript then you can generally assume that it is the Euclidean norm.